# SpringBoot does not get MultipartFile from Post request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to upload a multipart file in SpringBoot, But when I make a post request with the image in the body SpringBoot does not get the image file.

Here is a simplified sample of my code which presents the above problem (PostImage method returns -2):

```
@PostMapping("/Users/Image")
int PostImage(@RequestBody MultipartFile Image){
    if( Image == null ) return -2;
    return 0;
}
```

For the post request I tried both a REST client, and making the request from the frontend.
Any help will be greatly appreciated since I am now starting to learn SprinBoot.

REST client screenshot:[image]

**Edit**

By changing the @RequestBody to @RequestParam("file"), and making the field name "file" on my frontend application (angular) I was able to make the request. I haven't succeed to POST with REST client though.

Answer (score 1):

For your `@RestController` method, try `@RequestParam MultipartFile Image`.  For your MVC `@Controller`, I suggest you define a form:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor                                                              
@Getter @Setter                                                                 
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false) @ToString @Log4j2                         
public class Form {                                                      
    private MultipartFile file;                                                 
}
```

And do something like:

```java
    @RequestMapping(method = { POST }, value = { "/Users/Image" })                                   
    public String PostImage(..., @Valid Form form, BindingResult result) {  
        try {                                                                   
            if (! result.hasErrors()) {                                         
                ...                             
                MultipartFile file = form.getFile();             
                ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately now I get an exception "org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found" which as far as I can tell still means that no file was sent even though there is an image in the request. I will try to fix and propose a solution. Thank you again.

Comment: Good luck.  I suggest for next steps (if you haven't already) that you make sure the "field name" you enter in the REST client matches "Image" (or change your parameter name accordingly and/or use `@RequestParam(name="Image")`).

Comment: I change both the field name and the way I make the request on angular and it worked, I was never able to post through the REST client though, but I will check it on another day since my main focus is the FrontEnd (Angular).